# locate missing html tags in emacs

Tags: emacs, text-editor, html

How can I validate that all tags have been closed in emacs?

```
<div>
hi
<div id="2">
hello
<div>
```

The above being a very simple example of a missing div. How can i see in emacs which html tag is missing?

Comment: [Nxhtml](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/nXhtml/doc/nxhtml.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is XHTML, nxml-mode can validate it automatically. That's what I am using. (I.e. I switch to nxml-mode for validation, though I usually use html-mode.)

Comment: so how do i know, in case i load a pre written html file?

Comment: I don't understand your question, know what? All you have to do to make the validation work is open the file in the buffer and switch to nxml-mode (i.e. `M-x nxml-mode`). Then nxml-mode will display the next error in the minibuffer, you can jump there with `C-c C-n`. Actually the validation is done by the minor mode `rng-validate-mode`, it can be toggled with `C-c C-v`.